# Crystal Reports - Changing Table Locations No working

Tags: sql, .net, crystal-reports

I have an application developed in VB6 which I am migrating to .Net Framework 4.0. There is a report that works correctly in the original application but the migrated application does not work on the original application. As a special feature, this report changed at runtime attribute "location" in two tables (actually they are seen) used to generate the SQL with which the report is fed, but when "shooting" the reporete the changes in tables with the attribute "location" are not reflected, that I can display using the "SQL Server Profiler" tool:

`objReportDocument.Database.Tables(0).Location = "NameReferenceTable""`

My point is this: When the report was build, they used 5 database tables of the data base: Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4 and Table5.  Later, in de data base, the tables Table1 and Table2 were deleted.  The idea is that en run time a store procedure  constructed Table1 and Table2 like temporary tables with the original name more any id string; this new data base tables must be used when the report are rise.

When you walk over the Tables array of the report (ReportDocument.DataBase.Tables(n)), for each table you can see two key properties: Name and Location. I understand than Location propertie indicates to Crystal Reports with which tables should work to build the reorts, this is true?

I have not much experience with Crystal Reports, I investigated two weeks why this error is generated without an answer ... I hope you can help me a bit, I really appreciate it.

regards,

Fabian.

Comment: Does your report use any SubReports?  I ran into some issues as well when migrating our Crystal Reports to using .NET version.  If you have any SubReports, you need to loop through them recursively (in case there are any sub-subreports, etc.) and set the information on them as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
In this case, I am not using subreports.

Comment: Hopefully you can make use of the method I posted in my answer below.  You didn't specify if you were using VB.NET or C#, but the code I provided is from a VB.NET project of course.

Comment: Hi, thanks again!
Review your method, all the logic described are implements in my application: log in for each database table, etc.

When you walk over the Tables array of the report (ReportDocument.DataBase.Tables(n)), for each table you can see two key properties: Name and Location. I understand than Location propertie indicates to Crystal Reports with which tables should work to build the reorts, this is true?

Comment: Yes, according to intellisense, the `Location` property "Gets or sets the location of the database table".  Not only do you have to set it for each table, but as you can see below, looping through each `Section` of the report and recursively apply the properties to them as well.

Comment: Looking back, you said you do not use any subreports, so looping through the `Sections` may not be necessary.  Probably a good idea to add it anyway, in case you add any subreports in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally find the solution...

1. In my conection to BD use ODBC, the associate user to this conection no had a schema associate in the BD, then when the store procedure created the temporaly tables there are creates below the shchema bdo, but when crystal reports rise the report (used my ODBC with the associate user) no found the temporaly tables. So I associated a scheemma to the user used in my ODBC.
2. My original reports are old, then I had to open each one in VS2012,  overwrite the report to update the format and test in Main Report Preview.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a method that I use for our Crystal Reports objects in my application.  This is just used to set the login information for the report (our reports use built-in security), but if I am understanding your problem correctly, then you should be able to add/modify this method to set the `Location` as well.

The properties used in the method below are:

`Me.ConnectionInfo` is type `CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo`

`Me.LogOnInfo` is type `CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo`

`Me.Report` is type `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument`

Also, `g_strDb`, `g_strServer`, and `g_strMirror` are some `String`s whose value is irrelevant.

One thing I have found working with Crystal Reports in .NET, is that you need to set properties at the `Table` level, as you can see in the method below.  Hopefully this helps you with your issue.

```
''' <summary>
''' Apply the database connection info to all tables recursively.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="crxRpt">The report document (or subreport) to apply connection info.</param>
Private Sub SetConnectionInfo(ByVal crxRpt As ReportDocument)
    Dim reportObject As ReportObject
    Dim subReportObject As SubreportObject
    Dim section As Section
    Dim t As Table

    For Each t In crxRpt.Database.Tables
        ' if the DatabaseName in the report is <special db name>,
        ' we need to make sure to set the DatabaseName to the environment
        ' that the user is currently connected to in order to be able to
        ' pull the correct information for the report
        If t.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "<special db name>" Then
            Me.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = g_strDb
        Else
            Me.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = t.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName
        End If

        ' only ApplyLogOnInfo for tables that are being pulled from the SQL
        ' server, this avoids problems that arise with reports that are
        ' created using field definition files
        If t.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = g_strServer OrElse t.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = g_strMirror Then
            t.ApplyLogOnInfo(Me.LogOnInfo)
        End If
    Next t

    For Each section In crxRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections
        For Each reportObject In section.ReportObjects
            If reportObject.Kind = ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject Then
                subReportObject = CType(reportObject, CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.SubreportObject)
                SetConnectionInfo(subReportObject.OpenSubreport(subReportObject.SubreportName))
            End If
        Next reportObject
    Next section
End Sub
```

The above method is called from a setup method:

```
''' <summary>
''' Initialize the database connection info.
''' </summary>
Public Sub SetUpReport()
    Me.LogOnInfo = New TableLogOnInfo

    Me.ConnectionInfo.UserID = conUID
    Me.ConnectionInfo.Password = conPWD
    Me.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = g_strServer
    Me.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = g_strDb

    Me.SetConnectionInfo(Me.Report)
End Sub
```

And `SetUpReport()` is called any time we need to display/print the report.